# Setting image source in view model in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I want to be able to set my image source by binding it to a property in my view model -- see below:

```
public partial class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   ImageSource myImageSource;

   void Init()
   {
        if(somevalue == "something")
           MyImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("image_a.png");
        else
           MyImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("image_b.png");
   }
}
```

And in my XAML page< I do this:

```
<Image
   Source{Binding MyImageSource}
   HeightRequest="30"
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

This doesn't display the image but no errors. In my view model, I also tried `MyImageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("MyProject.Resources.Images.image_a.png");` which also doesn't display the image.

The images I want to display are in `Resources > Images` folder.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I set the image source to a file in a folder under `Resources` through my view model?

Comment: Just use string. "a.png" is perfectly fine.

Comment: Tried that but didn't work

Comment: How can It not work, when I am using it all the time :)

Comment: What is your property type in the view model? `string` or `ImageSource`?

Comment: Also, do you just use the filename or include the path as well? So far, I tried it as `string` with just filename and it doesn't work.

Comment: Its not string. It is ImageSource. Write this: MyImageSource = "dotnet_bot.png". The "dotnet_bot.png" is without path, because you already defined this path in your project, when you told that this maui image.

Comment: I added some code, if you have any questions, why and how it works, ask. Also it is Source={Binding MyImageSource}. You are missing "=".

Comment: `Fromfile` worked after appending Images folder, i.e. `MyImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("Images/image_b.png");` Image buildaction is Mauiimage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In project:

```
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
```

File in folder:

```
Resources/Images/dotnet_bot.svg
```

Define:

```
[ObservableProperty]
ImageSource image;
```

Use:

```
Image = "dotnet_bot.png";
```

Answer (score 2):

A method is to set your images's `Build Action` to `Embedded resource` and set value for `MyImageSource` in your view Model constructor,just as follows:

```
public partial  class MyViewModel:ObservableObject 
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        ImageSource myImageSource;
    
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            MyImageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("YourAppName.Resources.Images.test.png", typeof(MyViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly); 
        }
       
        }
    }
```

And bind like this:

```
<Image   Source="{Binding MyImageSource }" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="50"   HeightRequest="50" />
```

**Note:**

1.`YourAppName` is the name of the app,you can change it to yours.

2.Please change your images' `Build Action` to `Embedded resource`

Comment: Where do we find the App Name in the project?