# Vs fails to compile .NET MAUI project

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, maui

I have tried to run my project Buy it shows an error like this.

Severity    Code    Description Path    File    Line    Column  Suppression State

Error   APT2144 invalid file path 'C:\Prakash\Git\myappMobile\myapp\myapp\obj\Debug\net7.0-android\res\values\appicon.png'.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.68\tools C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.68\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets  123 3

i had tried :

the respective PNG file is on the path and the file path exists in File Explorer

clean solution and built it again show the same error

Comment: I got the same error for Android, iOS was working file. The solution worked for me was like: Delete all obj & bin folders manually, restart VS & replace the png file with a lower resolution. My png was large 2000x2000+.

Have you check the build properties of that png? it must be mauiImage

Comment: You can check this answer about [how to set the image source in maui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75692895/19335715).